# Have spacecraft photographed each other beyond Earth orbit?

Tags: deep-space, photography

There are several answers to [Could a spy satellite image another satellite?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/14002/12102) and one answer with several examples to [How many spacecraft have taken a “Pale Blue Dot” type photo of the Earth from beyond cis-lunar space?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/22838/12102)

And there are many photos of one spacecraft in cis-lunar space from another *taken by astronauts.*

**Question:** Are there any photos of one spacecraft taken *by another spacecraft* beyond Earth orbit?

Comment: Are you looking for objects still in space (i.e. not on a planet, like some Mars rovers?), or any spacecraft photos from another spacecraft, wherever it may be?

Comment: @BruceWayne There's a tendency to refer to historical and current landers and rovers as spacecraft; they are all by necessity designed to be space-worthy and some are even fairly active in space, and the planetary environments have a mix of space-like aspects (extreme temperature, low pressure, elevated radiation, low light levels) depending on the destination, so in general they count. However if/when vehicles are *built on the surface of Mars* exclusively for driving on Mars they definitely won't be considered spacecraft.

Answer (score 79):

Yes, here is a picture of the Curiosity lander spacecraft taken by the Mars  Reconnaissance Orbiter.  The picture was taken about one minute prior to the landing of Curiosity.

[image]

Image from https://www.space.com/16946-mars-rover-landing-seen-from-space.html

If landed craft are allowed, there are also pictures of Mars rovers from Mars orbiters, asteroid landers from their motherships, etc.

Comment: Imaged during "minute six of terror", or "minute of terror six"? This is a beautiful choreography of spacecraft, assuming that it wasn't a coincidence.

Comment: This answer is "technically correct". The best kind of correct! :D

Comment: I think landed craft [can definitely be allowed](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/40390/have-spacecraft-photographed-each-other-beyond-earth-orbit/40407#comment131072_40390)

Answer (score 55):

## The Mars Odyssey orbiter was photographed by Mars Global Surveyor in 2005.

- https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Mgs_odyssey.gif
- https://photojournal.jpl.nasa.gov/catalog/PIA07941

[image: PIA07941: Mars Odyssey from Two Distances in One Image]

> Figure 1: Why There are Two Images of Odyssey
>   NASA's Mars Odyssey spacecraft appears twice in the same frame in this image from the Mars Orbiter Camera aboard NASA's Mars Global Surveyor. The camera's successful imaging of Odyssey and of the European Space Agency's Mars Express in April 2005 produced the first pictures of any spacecraft orbiting Mars taken by another spacecraft orbiting Mars.
>
> Mars Global Surveyor and Mars Odyssey are both in nearly circular, near-polar orbits. Odyssey is in an orbit slightly higher than that of Global Surveyor in order to preclude the possibility of a collision. However, the two spacecraft occasionally come as close together as 15 kilometers (9 miles).
>
> The images were obtained by the Mars Global Surveyor operations teamsat Lockheed Martin Space System, Denver; JPL and Malin Space ScienceSystems.
>
> The two views of Mars Odyssey in this image were acquired a little under 7.5 seconds apart as Odyssey receded from a close flyby of Mars Global Surveyor. The geometry of the flyby (see Figure 1) and the camera's way of acquiring an image line-by-line resulted in the two views of Odyssey in the same frame. The first view (right) was taken when Odyssey was about 90 kilometers (56 miles) from Global Surveyor and moving more rapidly than Global Surveyor was rotating, as seen from Global Surveyor. A few seconds later, Odyssey was farther away -- about 135 kilometers (84 miles) -- and appeared to be moving more slowly. In this second view of Odyssey (left), the Mars Orbiter Camera's field-of-view overtook Odyssey.
>
> The Mars Orbiter Camera can resolve features on the surface of Mars as small as a few meters or yards across from Mars Global Surveyor's orbital altitude of 350 to 405 kilometers (217 to 252 miles). From a distance of 100 kilometers (62 miles), the camera would be able to resolve features substantially smaller than 1 meter or yard across.
>
> Mars Odyssey was launched on April 7, 2001, and reached Mars on Oct. 24, 2001. Mars Global Surveyor left Earth on Nov. 7, 1996, and arrived in Mars orbit on Sept. 12, 1997. Both orbiters are in an extended mission phase, both have relayed data from the Mars Exploration Rovers, and both are continuing to return exciting new results from Mars. JPL, a division of the California Institute of Technology, Pasadena, manages both missions for NASA's Science Mission Directorate, Washington, D.C.
>
> Image Credit: NASA/JPL/MSSS
>
> Image Addition Date: 2005-05-19

Comment: It photographed Mars Express also!  https://www.nasa.gov/vision/universe/solarsystem/mgs-images.html

Comment: Did they do this just for fun, or was there a science reason for it?

Comment: @IgbyLargeman Yes.

Comment: IMO this is the best answer, as it features an orbiter photographing another orbiter. The only thing better would have been if one of the two craft hadn't been in orbit around the same body (e.g. one craft in orbit around a planet and one craft slingshotting around the planet). An orbiter taking a photo of its own lander is relatively trivial.

Comment: @ceilingcat My sides...

Comment: @Draco18snolongertrustsSE The Curiosity lander was not Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter's "own lander", they are two completely different missions.

Answer (score 31):

some examples:

- LRO [images of the Apollo landing sites](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/LRO/multimedia/lroimages/apollosites.html). This is Apollo 11:

[image]

- Cassini and [Huygens](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/resources/12249/cassini-snaps-image-of-esas-huygens-probe/): this is Huygens as seen by Cassini, 12 hours after Huygens was released.

[image]

- Rosetta and Philae. During [descent](https://spaceflightnow.com/2014/11/13/rosetta-camera-captures-philaes-descent-to-the-comet/):

[image]

Philae's [final landing location](https://www.dlr.de/content/en/articles/news/2016/20160905_comet-lander-philae-found_19204.html):

[image]

- Hayabusa 2 and its many landers. This is a photo of Minerva-II-2 taken by Hayabusa 2:

[image]

Comment: The LRO/Apollo pictures are in Earth orbit, though, since even though LRO is orbiting the Moon, both are still orbiting Earth.

Comment: that's just hairsplitting.

Comment: @Hobbes I also thought I remembered a picture of Huygens as it was leaving Cassini, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: That [X/Motif](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motif_(software)) window border though.

Answer (score 18):

For a case with more extreme relative motion than most of the other answers, the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter (polar orbit) [imaged the LADEE orbiter](http://lroc.sese.asu.edu/posts/736) (close to equatorial orbit) in 2014:

[image: LADEE orbiter from LRO (not aspect corrected)]

The LADEE appears rather distorted because the image was taken with a [pushbroom camera](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_broom_scanner), not the more familiar framing camera, so LADEE moves between lines relative to the background.  However, once that's corrected the barrel-shaped LADEE is mostly identifiable:

[image: LADEE orbiter from LRO (aspect corrected)]

*(Image credit NASA/GSFC/Arizona State University)*

Answer (score 16):

You can also find photos of some Mars rovers from various orbiters/satellites:

[Opportunity from Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://www.space.com/27-latest-mars-shots-spirit-opportunity.html)

> After a planet-wide dust storm in June 2018 blocked the Opportunity rover's solar panels, NASA scientists waited for images from the planet to clear. This image, captured Sept. 20 by the Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter, was among the key signs that the sky was clearing, since engineers could see the rover again. The image was taken from 166 miles (267 kilometers) above the surface of Mars.

[image]

And [another photo](https://www.space.com/27-latest-mars-shots-spirit-opportunity/5.html)

[image]

And [yet another from the MRO](https://www.space.com/27-latest-mars-shots-spirit-opportunity/7.html):

> A close-up of the Opportunity rover perched at the southeast rim of Mars' Santa Maria crater.

[image]

Here's one of the [Insight Lander](https://www.nasa.gov/feature/jpl/mars-insight-lander-seen-in-first-images-from-space/):

> NASA's InSight spacecraft, its heat shield and its parachute were imaged on Dec. 6 and 11 by the HiRISE camera onboard NASA's Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In a similar vein to Organic Marble's [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40393/27371):

The [Phoenix lander](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/phoenix/main.php) was [captured](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=1715) during its [descent on May 25, 2008](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/phoenix/images/press/9227-PHX_Lander.html), hanging from its parachute with crater Heimdall in the distant background, and again after landing on Mars and deploying its solar panels, by the HiRISE camera on [Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/missions/mars-reconnaissance-orbiter-mro/).

[image: Phoenix during its descent down to Mars in front of Heimdall crater]
(Source: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/phoenix/images.php?fileID=9448.
In my personal opinion, this is one of the most stunning pictures of this kind ever taken.)

[image: Phoenix on the surface of Mars]
(Source: https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/phoenix/images.php?fileID=9770)

Comment: Agreed, that's an awesome picture indeed.

Answer (score 7):

From [this answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23669/12102):

> In the Planetary Society's Senior Editor and Planetary Evangelist [Emily Lakdawalla](http://www.planetary.org/about/staff/emily-lakdawalla.html)'s article [Fun with a new data set: Chang'e 3 lander and Yutu rover camera data](http://www.planetary.org/blogs/emily-lakdawalla/2016/01281656-fun-with-a-new-data-set-change.html) there are several photos from 
>   Chang'e-3 and the Yutu rover.

[image: Chang'e-3 and the Yutu rover]

**above:** Chang'e 3 photographed by the Yutu rover, January 13, 2014 [read more](https://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/earth/change-3-lander-in-the-distance.html)

> Chinese Academy of Sciences / China National Space Administration / The Science and Application Center for Moon and Deepspace Exploration / Emily Lakdawalla

**below:** Yutu rover photographed by Chang'e 3 December 23, 2013 [read more](https://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/earth/yutu-on-the-road.html)

> Chinese Academy of Sciences / China National Space Administration / The Science and Application Center for Moon and Deepspace Exploration / Emily Lakdawalla

[image: Yutu rover photographed by Chang'e 3]

---

From Planetary Society's Editorial Directors [Jason Davis](http://www.planetary.org/about/staff/emily-lakdawalla.html)'s post [Chang'e-4 deploys rover on far side of the Moon](https://www.planetary.org/blogs/jason-davis/change4-deploys-yutu-2.html) there is a photo of Yutu-2 being deployed from Chang'e 4. It is likely that there is a reciprocal photo of Chang'e-4 from Yutu-2 but I haven't found one yet.

[image: Yutu-2 being deployed from Chang'e-4]

**above:**  Yutu-2 being deployed from Chang'e-4 as photographed by Chang'e-4 [read more](https://www.planetary.org/multimedia/space-images/spacecraft/yutu-2-with-six-wheels-on-the-moon.html)

> The rover rolled onto the surface at 14:22 on 3 January 2019, CNSA / CLEP

Comment: Really interesting pictures.

Answer (score 6):

NASA [photographed what was left of the India Vikram Lunar Lander](https://www.engadget.com/2019/12/03/vikram-lunar-lander-crash-site/) from the Lunar Reconnaissance Orbiter

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yet *another* example, this time involving a spacecraft that was photographed *twice*, by two different other spacecraft, beyond Earth orbit.  The *[Beagle 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beagle_2)* Mars lander hitchhiked to Mars on the back of *[Mars Express](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Express)*, and, in a similar vein to [*Cassini–Huygens* above](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/40394/23891), *Mars Express* photographed *Beagle 2* after the two separated:

[image: _Mars Express_ (b. 2003): __Beagle 2__, 2003. CMOS digital camera photograph.]

(Image by the European Space Agency, via [Flickr](https://www.flickr.com/photos/esa_marswebcam/8264016660/), via Cassioli at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=File:Beagle-2-separation.png), via Huntster at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Beagle-2-separation.png). 
 *Beagle 2* is the round thing on the far left.)

*Beagle 2* failed shortly after touchdown, and it remained missing until the [Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter) [photographed it in 2015](https://www.nasa.gov/jpl/lost-2003-mars-lander-found-by-mars-reconnaissance-orbiter/):

[image: alas, poor _Beagle 2_! I knew him, Horatio - oh, wait, no, I didn't, nevermind.]

(Image by [NASA](https://www.nasa.gov/sites/default/files/thumbnails/image/pia19107_mro-beagle-merged.jpg), via Drbogdan at [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:PIA19107-Beagle2-Found-MRO-20140629.jpg).)

Answer (score 5):

The Apollo 13 Service Module was photographed from the Apollo 13 LEM on the way back to Earth.

Not sure if this is what you were looking for since they were part of the same mission, were on the way back to Earth and were not far away when they separated and the pictures were taken. On the other hand, they were NOT in orbit.

[image]

Comment: Not in orbit? How's that.

Comment: This doesn't count technically because an *astronaut* took this photo (re-read he 2nd sentence of the question) but it's a good reminder. Also, since the Moon is in orbit around the Earth, anything cis-lunar is in orbit around the Earth.

Comment: This photo was taken from the command module preparing for re-entry, not from the LEM.

Comment: @OrganicMarble, the command and service modules were both on re-entry trajectories when the photo was taken.

Comment: @Mark an orbit that intersects a body or atmosphere is still an orbit.