# What actually happened here with a satellite, the ISS and the moon?

Tags: iss, the-moon, artificial-satellite

I can't follow exactly what happened from this [string of tweets](https://twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720254837095575552) - I'm not really twitter-literate. It seems like there was a predicted conjunction of the ISS with the moon, and an actual video of what *could be* a satellite crossing in front of the moon.

However, it looks like the trajectory is roughly parallel to the moon's terminator?

*Can anyone reconstruct this?* We have a timestamp, a distinct crater [Theophilus](https://twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720541433837568000) on the terminator, and possible IDs both as a Russian satellite and a Ferrari. Are there "reverse-satellite-lookups?"

https://twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720254837095575552

Manual Screenshot of the tweet, showing (presumably) a speeding satellite as a little blurred white thing moving roughly parallel to the moon's terminator. The tweeted image says it's a GIF, [but it's not!](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/742/12102)

[image: screen shot of tweet]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I had difficulty with the site in the other answer, so I tried [a newer website](https://in-the-sky.org/).

It turns out the ISS did indeed pass by the moon about a minute later.

Home-made GIF from screenshots:

The **Moon** is the **Purple Dot** and **CRS-8** is shown together with **ISS**

**TIME in UTC** is shown just above the image on the left.

[image]

The satellite that transited the moon seen from the Royal Observatory is [Reseurs DK-1](http://space.skyrocket.de/doc_sdat/resurs-dk.htm) a Russian civilian remote-sensing spacecraft (i.e. [0.9m resolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resurs-DK_No.1) *earth-pointing telescope*) that looks [pretty amazing](http://www.russianspaceweb.com/resurs_dk.html)! .

[image: russianspaceweb.com/resurs_dk.html]

Here is the screenshot again from the original [tweeted GIF](https://twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720254837095575552) which is really a [faux-GIF](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/a/742/12102). The short white streak in the lower-left is probably the DK-1 satellite moving fast in LEO. Since this is just after sunset locally, the satellite, at an altitude of 572km here, is probably still in full sunlight and therefore very bright!

[image: screenshot twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720254837095575552]

The crater is [Theophilus](https://twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720541433837568000) and this image from the linked tweet shows the sun rising on the [central peak](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_craters#Characteristics) of the crater, taken with the [28 inch Refractor at the Royal Observatory Grenwich](http://www.royalobservatorygreenwich.org/articles.php?article=1174).

[image: from twitter.com/ROGAstronomers/status/720541433837568000]

The crater is nearest the Apollo 16 landing site.

[image: Theophilus crater in google.com/moon]

The satellite trajectory data was obtained [like this](https://in-the-sky.org/). I used user-specified location instead of the **London** preset, to make sure the time was UTC.

[image: in-the-sky.org setup]

Answer (score 3):

I just used the [CalSky web tool](http://www.calsky.com/cs.cgi).  When set up for a location and a timeframe, this should be able to predict close ISS passes to the sun or moon.

When I set it up for London, there are no ISS passes that close to the moon for that date.

But trying the Resurs DK-1 satellite shows a good match.

[This link](http://www.calsky.com/csrender.cgi?object=Satellite&number=11&obs=41347974266773&tdt=2457491.34089252&sat=29228&skymap=) should show the pass from london at that time.  You can see it shows a pass near the moon along the general direction of the terminator.

Comment: The link doesn't work for me - it resets to current time and my local coordinates.  When I change to 12-4-2016 20:15:00 UT, and Grenwich, London, UK (51.48N, 0.0E)  [I DO see the ISS pass next to the moon](http://i.imgur.com/r0e2ixR.png) and a larger [ZOOM shown here](http://i.imgur.com/KGa6U2C.png), but I don't know how to add the satellites.

Comment: After you set the location and timezone,  Click the "satellites" tab, then underneath, "satellites within interval".  On that page, set the time and a short interval.  After you hit "go" you should be able to scroll down and see sats visible from during the interval.  One is DK-1.  On that line, click the "star chart" link.

Comment: I can't get it to work for some reason. I was able to generate those maps in my first comment showing the ISS passing the moon, which seems to be at about 19:38  **BST** which is **daylight time** and would be 20:38 UTC. Apparently the site uses local time and you have to KNOW if it is daylight time or not - times are listed without reference to what  time zone is used! However it seems that there WAS a pass of the ISS near the moon.

Comment: Timezone is set in intro.  Step 1 is location, Step 2 is timezone.  Once that is set, should be easier to plug in the time and see the sat passes.