# Did Huygens take a picture of Cassini?

Tags: cassini, camera

In reference to a [question about pictures of Cassini](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/23049/195), I stated that it was possible that Huygens could have tested out its camera immediately after separation by taking a picture of Cassini.

Was this actually done? Did Huygens take any pictures of its mothership prior to its descent to Titan's surface?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, Huygens would not have been able to take a picture of Cassini.  Huygen's camera was part of the Descent Imager/Spectral Radiometer [instrument package](http://www.esa.int/Our_Activities/Space_Science/Cassini-Huygens/Huygens_instruments).  As seen in this cutaway from [GSFC](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/spacecraft/huygens_cutaway.jpg), the DISR port is on the side of the spacecraft.  This port would have been entirely covered by the [heat shield](http://www.imperial.ac.uk/ImageCropToolT4/imageTool/uploaded-images/Huygens-5--tojpeg_1446038171732_x2.jpg).  Therefore, the very design of Huygens would have prevented it from being able to take any images until after the heat shield had been jettisoned.  Plus, Huygens had no directional controls, so it could not have pointed itself back at Cassini to take a picture.

[image]

Comment: Ah, didn't realize it lacked any active attitude control. Thanks!